# Not able to email the textbox data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, email, timeout

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("gahlotprayank@yahoo.com", "*******")
        SmtpServer.Port = 465
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("gahlotprayank@yahoo.com")
        mail.To.Add("rebelme23@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = TextBox1.Text
        mail.Body = TextBox2.Text
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("ok!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

i tried the above code but got the error saying "timeout" and couldn't mail the textbox data

[image]

Comment: your from address does not match the address in the credentials. Could be a rejection?

Comment: i made those same but still ERROR.... can u suggest me sending these text field data through FTP

Answer (score 1):

The time out is likely server related and has nothing to do with your text box value. Are you sure that you have permission to use yahoo's mail server to send email?

Comment: @ logixologist HOW CAN I DO THIS USING FTP INSTEAD OF SMTP AND ALL THIS MAIL STUFF ????

Comment: why would you FTP the value of a textbox.... you just need to find an email server that allows you to Relay from. I used to be able to go to www.smtp.com and purchase a relay account.

Comment: Also I  noticed your port is 465??

Comment: yahoomail smtp server port number is 465 and same is for gmail also.
i need to store the values somewhere and that can be done by getting a free web hosting and providing those ftp details in the code but i dont know how?

Comment: Can you go into your yahoo account settings and see if there is a setting for Relay. Relay needs to be turned on.

Comment: `code` Net.NetworkCredential("rebelme23@gmail.com", "rebelme@23")
            SmtpServer.Port = 465
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("rebelme23@gmail.com")
            mail.To.Add("rebelme23@gmail.com")
            mail.Subject = TextBox1.Text
            mail.Body = TextBox2.Text
            SmtpServer.Send(mail) `code`

Comment: i tried changing everything to gmail but still its not working and these credentials work on another application which does the same things as sends some data to email but i dont have source code of that..

Answer (score 0):

Try using "smtp.gmail.com" port: 587
Then enable the "access for less secure apps" option of your email account